# Sending my IP-Adress to MongoDB over Node.js Server

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I am running an Mongo Atlas Server and a Node.js Rest-Api for that Server hosted on Heroku. Connecting to the Mongo Server via. mongoose and express.js. When i was setting up the Mongo Server i whitelisted all Ip-Addresses. So my Question is:

1. When connecting with my Client-Application to the Rest-Api->Mongo Server does my IP-Adress get somehow send/parsed to my MongoDB Server.
2. Or would it be enough just to whitelist the "IP"(dont rly know if that exists) of my Rest-Api?

Answer (score 0):

Your MongoDB server would receive the IP address of the connecting instance. In this case, if your call is routed via the REST API, the IP address shared (and needs whitelisting) is the server where your REST API is hosted (which is Heroku, if I understand correctly).